# WP8 issue with html agility pack

Tags: windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

This is the function I used to get the string content from the website ..the problem is when executed first I cannot get the string content (`App.Data2 = userprofile.InnerText;`) since it skips to the next line (`App.savecontent(App.Data2);`) so that I get an empty string. If I recall the function I could get the string. Is there any possibility to solve this issue I need the string value first time automatically

This is my Page.cs code :

```
namespace Project_Future1
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {    
        public  Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            {
                string url = "http://www.astrosage.com/horoscope/daily-";
                HtmlWeb.LoadAsync(url + App.Data + "-horoscope.asp", DownLoad);
            } 
            data();

            App.loadContent();
            change2();
        }

        public void change2()
        {
            try
            {
              Util.LiveTile.UpdateLiveTile(App.Data2);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        public void DownLoad(object sender, HtmlDocumentLoadCompleted e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                HtmlDocument doc =  e.Document;
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    var userprofile = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'ui-large-content']");

                    App.Data2 =   userprofile.InnerText;
                    App.savecontent(App.Data2); 
                }
            } 
        }

        private void data()
        {
            SelectedSign.Text = App.Data;
            SSContent.Text = App.Data2;
        }

        private void Refresh_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SSContent.Text = App.Data2;
        }


        private void Fb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FB.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

this is my App.Xaml.cs File :

```
public static void savecontent(string save)
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appFileName1))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile oIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            oIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(appFolder1);
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(appFolder1 + "\\" + appFileName1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, oIsolatedStorage));

            writeFile.WriteLine(save);
            writeFile.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

this is my code to load the content from the storage :

```
public static void loadContent()
{
    IsolatedStorageFile oIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (oIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(appFolder1))
    {
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = oIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(appFolder1 + "\\" + appFileName1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            App.Data2 = reader.ReadLine();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your post by adding `*.savecontent();` full code?

Comment: I updated with that code

Comment: So you get the string content only if you call two times: `App.savecontent(App.Data2)` ?

Comment: I am confused with this! wen i navigate to the page i call loadcontent func it doest give me the string in my textbox but when i press refresh the loadcontent function is called again  and I could get the content.But this is not working at the time of page navigation .thts the problem

Comment: @fiskerXO can you help me with this?

Comment: Well, I guess there is a possible issue with double assign. For instance I would write : `App.Data2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class = 'ui-large-content']").InnerText;`.  And also it is a bit weird, because for each string you create again and again a new folder and a new file. I would rather create it outside of your method and in your `savecontent()` method I would just write in an existing file.

Comment: Thanks for making me remind about that folder creation I corrected it .But still the problem with getting that content remains the same .I done what u have said but no changes. As like before it comes after refreshing only.:/ Its so hard